# Does Repa specify its data's memory layout?

Tags: haskell, repa, memory-layout

I can't see that Repa specifies memory layouts for the data in any of its "manifest representations". Is this specified somewhere?

Of course I can find out through experimentation, but I'd rather know if the layout is official or prone to change at any time.

**Edit:** To clarify, I understand how a `Storable` `Vector` is laid out, but I wonder whether `Array U DIM2 Double` (for example) is row-major, column-major, or something crazy.

Comment: Aside: I do know that one doesn't have to care about this when using Repa itself. In my case, however, I have to do some FFI with the data as well, so getting the layout straight (preferably across many releases of Repa) is of some importance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory layouts for data are defined by their type class instances of [unboxed vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-Repr-Unboxed.html):

> The implementation uses @Data.Vector.Unboxed@ which is based on type
>   families and picks an efficient, specialised representation for every
>   element type. In particular, unboxed vectors of pairs are represented
>   as pairs of unboxed vectors.

To see the layout specification of vectors, check the instances for unboxed vectors [defined in the vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Base.html#Vector), where e.g. Bool is represented with bytes:

```
newtype instance MVector s Bool = MV_Bool (P.MVector s Word8)
```

while if we dive down the rabbit hole to the primitive arrays package, you see the [alignment and size constraints for the primitive types](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primitive/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Primitive-Types.html#Prim). According to Repa 1, manifest (allocated) arrays are filled in [row major](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#1). The docs for the latest version also support this.

> I have to do some FFI with the data as well, so getting the layout straight

Since you have to interoperate with C code (or something else), then it is vital to use [Storable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Storable.html) instances. These will guarantee that your types can be easily transferred to C (using C layout conventions, via the [ForeignPtr interface to Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-Repr-ForeignPtr.html), which ensures you safely map pointers to C-shaped foreign data to and from Repa.

Comment: Right, I know the layout of storable vectors, but I can't see that this gives me the layout of a Repa array. For example, is `Array U DIM2 Double` laid out as row-major, column-major, or (of course not, but in principle) in some other crazy way? I guess my question was unclear, so I'll update it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I never spotted your Feb 24, 17:53 edit. Thanks, this answers my question :)